# Compiler flags change code behavior (O2, Ox)

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, compiler-optimization, compiler-flags

The following code works as expected with flags Od, O1 but fails with O2, Ox. Any ideas why?

edit: by "fails" I mean that the function does nothing, and seems to just return.

```
void thread_sleep()
{
    listIterator nextThread = getNextThread();
    void * pStack = 0;
    struct ProcessControlBlock * currPcb = pPCBs->getData(currentThread);
    struct ProcessControlBlock * nextPcb = pPCBs->getData(nextThread);

    if(currentThread == nextThread)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        currentThread = nextThread;
        __asm pushad            // push general purpose registers
        __asm pushfd            // push control registers
        __asm mov pStack, esp   // store stack pointer in temporary

        currPcb->pStack = pStack;   // store current stack pointer in pcb
        pStack = nextPcb->pStack;   // grab new stack pointer from pcb

        if(nextPcb->state == RUNNING_STATE)// only pop if function was running before
        {
            __asm mov esp, pStack       // restore new stack pointer
            __asm popfd
            __asm popad;
        }
        else
        {
            __asm mov esp, pStack       // restore new stack pointer
            startThread(currentThread);
        }
    }
}
```

// After implementing suggestions: (still does not work)

```
listIterator nextThread = getNextThread();
struct ProcessControlBlock * currPcb = pPCBs->getData(currentThread);
struct ProcessControlBlock * nextPcb = pPCBs->getData(nextThread);
void * pStack = 0;
void * pNewStack = nextPcb->pStack; // grab new stack pointer from pcb
pgVoid2 = nextPcb->pStack;

if(currentThread == nextThread)
{
    return;
}
else
{
    lastThread = currentThread; // global var
    currentThread = nextThread;


    if(nextPcb->state == RUNNING_STATE)// only pop if function was running before
    {
        __asm pushad                // push general purpose registers
        __asm pushfd                // push control registers
        __asm mov pgVoid1, esp      // store stack pointer in temporary
        __asm mov esp, pgVoid2      // restore new stack pointer
        __asm popfd
        __asm popad;

        {
            struct ProcessControlBlock * pcb = pPCBs->getData(lastThread);
            pcb->pStack = pgVoid1; // store old stack pointer in pcb
        }
    }
    else
    {
        __asm pushad                // push general purpose registers
        __asm pushfd                // push control registers
        __asm mov pgVoid1, esp  // store stack pointer in temporary
        __asm mov esp, pgVoid2      // restore new stack pointer

        {
            struct ProcessControlBlock * pcb = pPCBs->getData(lastThread);
            pcb->pStack = pgVoid1; // store old stack pointer in pcb
        }
        startThread(currentThread);
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "fails"?

Comment: There might be some unseen bug which appears when applying a different optimization, and I've met such bug before.

Comment: It does not work as expected, the function is supposed to schedule another "thread" when called. By "fails" I mean that it is as-if the function is not executed at all, and returns instantly

Comment: Have you tried stepping through in the debugger?

Comment: The entire function is optimized out, so there's nothing to step through. When optimizations are turned off, it works as expected

Comment: Have you confirmed that by looking at the compiler output?

Comment: Are there any thread global var/s? Is access to those synchronise? If doing optimisation, it's most likely your apps runs significantly faster then without opt/ or even when being debugged. So this also could simply be a timing issues due to missing/wrong sync/ occurring only when the parallism behaves diffently as some parts of the apps are running faster then others suddenly.

Answer (score 3):

It is likely because your compiler is not using a specific frame pointer register on the higher optimisation levels, which frees up an additional general-purpose register.

This means that the compiler accesses the local variable `pStack` using an offset from the stack pointer.  It cannot do this correctly after the stack pointer has been adjusted by the `pushad` and `pushfd` - it is not expecting the stack pointer to change.

To get around this, you shouldn't put any C code after those `asm` statements, until the stack pointer has been correctly restored: everything from the first `pushad` to the `popad` or `startThread()` should be in assembler.  This way, you can load the address of the local variables and ensure that the accesses are done correctly.

Comment: I tried to get all the assembly to execute in a single block, it does not help the situation.

Answer (score 2):

As you use inline assembler, you'd probably want to see how's (or whether is) the code really modified when it's compiled with various -Ox options. Try this on your binary:

```
objdump -s your_program
```

It gives a heap of code, but finding the corresponding code section shouldn't be that hard (search for your assembly or for function names).

By the way, I was taught that heavy optimization doesn't do very well with inline assembly, so I tend to separate assembler routines to .S files because of this.